# DarkMode images in xamarin iOS in visual studio

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In android you can create a drawable-night folder and put your dark mode images there.

What is the process in iOS?
Do I create a folder?

I have visual studio 2019 very latest version. Do I need a mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Assets catalogue you can specify different items for the light and dark mode. As far as I can tell the UI to edit this is available only on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio on Windows (Community 2022, Version 17.16) you could add the Dark mode Appearance in the Properties Window of your Asset image set item.

[image: Properties of Asset item]